# WSO2 Analytics Hostname

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

API Manager 3.0.0 and Analytics 3.0.0

Actually API-M I changed to hostname with any problems. When I change to hostname of Analytics some erros to login:

Only  I change in [API-Analytics]/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml

**deployment.yaml**

```
## Authentication configuration
auth.configs:
  type: apim
  ssoEnabled: true
  properties:
    adminScope: apim_analytics:admin_carbon.super
    allScopes: apim_analytics:admin apim_analytics:product_manager apim_analytics:api_developer apim_analytics:app_developer apim_analytics:devops_engineer apim_analytics:analytics_viewer apim_analytics:$
    adminServiceBaseUrl: https://myhostname:9443
    adminUsername: admin
    adminPassword: admin
    kmDcrUrl: https://myhostname:9443/client-registration/v0.15/register
    kmTokenUrlForRedirection: https://myhostname:9443/oauth2
    kmTokenUrl: https://hostname:9443/oauth2
    kmUsername: admin
    kmPassword: admin
    portalAppContext: analytics-dashboard
    businessRulesAppContext : business-rules
    cacheTimeout: 900
    baseUrl: https://myhostname:9643
    grantType: authorization_code
    publisherUrl: https://myhostname:9443
    #storeUrl: https://myhostname:9443
```

If I have this error in terminal, after to start dashboard server.

`<ip adress> != <localhost>`

But I change myhostname to **localhost** no sends this errors but in login page of Dashboard sends:

https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=VACHtG8hNxzG2au1EcA3sNmmXooa&scope=apim_analytics%3Aadmin%20apim_analytics%3Aproduct_manager%20apim_analytics%3Aapi_developer%20apim_analytics%3Aapp_developer%20apim_analytics%3Adevops_engineer%20apim_analytics%3Aanalytics_viewer%20apim_analytics%3Aeveryone%20openid%20apim%3Aapi_view%20apim%3Asubscribe&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9643%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2Fanalytics-dashboard%2Flogin

So, how fix or changed hostanem correctly?

**Edit:**

I change only `kmTokenUrlForRedirection`,`kmTokenUrl` and `baseUrl` from deplymento.yaml and dashboard page I have:
[image]

I search the error and found this link https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/

But I try put somo **regexp** similar to:

regexp

```
regexp=(https://myhostname:9643/analytics-dashboard/login|https://myhostname:6443/analytics-dashboard/logout)
```

But nothing.
My new question is:
Where is a correct form of **regexp** of dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your analytics_dashboard sp's regex to following and try.

```
regexp=(https://myhostname:9643/login/callback/analytics-dashboard/login|https://myhostname:9643/analytics-dashboard)
```

Comment: I put the regex and send me the error: ``` 
invalid_callback
Registered callback does not match with the provided url.```

Comment: Can you try by deleting the analytics dashboard SP and try by restarting the dashboards server and logging into the dashboards.